# Glassfish vs Glassfish-web profile

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3

I know the GF-web profile is lighter weight compare to full GF, utilize less memory. But does the web-profile version run faster than the full version. My VPS is 4G memory, and I specify `-Xmx: 1400M`, `-Xms: 1400M` as well. I am currently using the full version GF open source. I wonder if I should switch over to the web profile version. I know the web profile version dont support JMS, but I think I can just download the mail.jar and put it into my classpath and it should work, right?

Comment: it may run faster than the full profile... but it will probably run at about the same speed.  It depends on the application that you are trying to run.

Answer (score 6):

GF can be configured in a very flexible way with the update tool. You can configure the full GF to act like a web profile. I would take the full version and remove every unecessairy feature, and you have an optimal profile for your situation. Try to avoid copying jars here and there.